# Configuring WorldImage data store starting from folder containing tif and tfw files

Tags: raster, geoserver

I have a folder of tif and tfw files and I would like to show the raster in a map using geoserver. Even reading the geoserver tutorial for this kind of datastore (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/worldimage.html) I couldn't find the way to show the raster. In the same folder, I also have other files (shape, aux, properties, ..) but I don't know if they are useful for publish the map or not.

I could not figure out how to configure the pyramid of tiff.

Is there a way to configure geoserver or directly OpenLayers in order to show the folder of tif?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add and single raster by going to "Add Raster Data Source":
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/geotiff.html

I don't believe you'll need anything other than TIF and ECW files.

---

Alternately, to load a directory of TIFs, you may wish to read this mailing list thread:
http://www.mail-archive.com/geoserver-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg08652.html